# PPTP VPN problem in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vpn, pptp

I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I have a problem with connecting to VPN using the PPTP.

Running `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager`

```
Jul  9 14:15:33 ThinkPad NetworkManager[1093]: <info>  [1657359933.2202] vpn[0x556e82738460,b8d91891-159c-4b46-8a71-32d0ab50313f,"KerioMaker | VPK-1"]: starting pptp
Jul  9 14:15:33 ThinkPad NetworkManager[1093]: <info>  [1657359933.2239] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="b8d91891-159c-4b46-8a71-32d0ab50313f" name="KerioMaker | VPK-1" pid=2162 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  9 14:15:33 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.9/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jul  9 14:15:33 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Using interface ppp0
Jul  9 14:15:33 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Jul  9 14:15:33 ThinkPad NetworkManager[1093]: <info>  [1657359933.5647] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
Jul  9 14:16:04 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Jul  9 14:16:04 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Connection terminated.
Jul  9 14:16:04 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Terminating on signal 15
Jul  9 14:16:04 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Child process /sbin/pptp 49.12.218.89 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-14945 (pid 14954) terminated with signal 15
Jul  9 14:16:04 ThinkPad NetworkManager[14951]: Modem hangup
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I see the same error in my logs.

Comment: No, I've been using cisco since posting this thread.